Нужно ли тире после "это"?
"Это (—) не привычная многим пятидневка, где отдых приходится на субботу и воскресенье..."

Постановка тире возможна, но при особом построении текста —  например, при наличии параллельной конструкции с противопоставлением:
Это — не привычная многим пятидневка, где отдых приходится на субботу и воскресенье... Это нечто другое.
Пояснение

Тире интонационное, но наличие подчеркнутой паузы после местоимения это нужно обосновать.

Пример: Это не магия. Это нечто другое.  Можно распространить первое предложение и поставить тире после это. Тогда местоимение будет логически подчеркнуто.
Это — не магия, как мы себе обычно ее представляем и которой не особенно доверяем. Это нечто другое.

Другой пример (оценка ранее сказанного с логическим подчеркиванием местоимения):

«Надейся на Господа всем сердцем твоим, и не полагайся на разум твой». Это — не одни только слова, как некоторым показалось, приобретшим по сей причине книги, узнавшим написанное в них, ничего из написанного не исполнившим на деле...
Розенталь § 5.Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым
7. При подлежащем, выраженном словом это, между главными 
членами предложения тире ставится в зависимости от 
логического выделения подлежащего и наличия паузы после 
него; ср.: Это — начало всех начал. — Это неплохое начало; 
Это — одиночество (Ч.). — Это дом Зверкова (Г.).

